# 30 ampere machine

Tags: electrical-power

I have a machine tha takes input of 30 ampere, and my power socket iof only 16amps, please advice wha chnges i will have to make??

Comment: Install a 30a plug. point.

Comment: Just changing the receptacle could be extremely dangerous.  You are likely to overload the circuit, and in the worst case cause a fire, or damage your equipment.

Comment: Not to forget you likely would loose every kind of insurance you might have and will be personal liable for this.

Comment: isn't it unlikely that he has a machine that takes 30 amps in the first place?

Comment: You're assuming its a computer. :) Might be shredding cars !

Answer (score 10):

Call an electrician. That is the only sane thing.